# Ruby: Looping through models to calculate ratios within nested hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, hash, nested

I'm building a spam filter for a job app (think tinder for jobs). I'm currently helping to build a spam filter. To achieve that goal, a signal for users who are "over-applying" for jobs is their apply-to-rejection ratio per day.

To inform our threshold, I've come up with a solution to gather that data from the db by using a nested hash i.e. `{user1 =>{date1=>0.33, date2=>0.66}}`. My problem now is that the ratios are all 1.0, because **i think** i'm looping up until either rejections or applications are all gone through so the calculation is always the same number divided by itself.

Here's what i got so far. Appreciate the help.

```
users = User.all
ratio_hash = Hash.new

users.each do |user|

  if user.job_applications.count > 0 && user.job_rejections.count > 0

    ratio_hash[user.name] = Hash.new

    apply_array = []
    reject_array = []

    user.job_rejections.each do |reject|
      user.job_applications.each do |apply|


        if (apply.user_id.present? && reject.user_id.present?) || rej.user_id.present?
          if (apply.user_id == user.id && reject.user_id == user.id) || rej.user_id == user.id
            if (apply.created_at.present? && reject.created_at.present?) || reject.created_at.present?

              date = (apply_array && reject.created_at.to_date)

              if (apply.created_at.to_date == reject.created_at.to_date) || reject.created_at.to_date == date
                apply_array << apply.created_at.to_date
                reject_array << reject.created_at.to_date
                ratio_hash[user.name][(apply.created_at.to_date || reject.created_at.to_date)] = (apply_array.length.round(2)/reject_array.length)
              end

            end
          end
        end

      end
    end

  end
```

end

Comment: This code makes very little sense to me for couple reasons. 1) `created_at` is automatically set by Rails so it makes no sense checking if it's present. 2)   presence of `user_id` is also probably checked on your application/rejection models. 3) Lastly, checking if `apply.user_id == user.id` when apply comes from `user.job_applications` makes absolutely no sense because obviously all applications will belong to that user.

Comment: Basically this whole code could be done in like two lines probably.

Comment: If you tell me what are the requirements (for how many last days you want to have a ratio, etc) I will show you how to do it better.

Comment: Yeah was making alot of redundant exception handling because our db isn't the cleanest atm. What I need to do exactly is to count the job Rejections and applications for a specific user for each orrucance date and find the ration for the day.

Comment: No matter how messy the db is at least my points 2 & 3 have to be valid because Rails wouldn't return those records otherwise. As to created_at... well, why would anyone mess with that field?